# addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask Alternative for Off-mainthread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-foundation

I currently use addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask to monitor mouse events and I call it from main thread. It works great. However I now want to move it to off the main thread. Is there an alternative like something like creating a hidden window from a thread and doing `NSRunLoop`?

I read on the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html

> The handlers are always called on the main thread. Both class methods return the monitor object, which the calling object does not own (and thus has no need to retain or release).

Is there any alternative that I can do from off main thread?

I can't setup callbacks on the mainthread from another thread. I'm using an FFI and its not capable of that right now.

Here is my code in case it helps, but I'm hoping for alternative to this for off main thread please:

```
myHandler_js = function(c_arg1__self, objc_arg1__aNSEventPtr) {

    var cType = ostypes.API('objc_msgSend')(objc_arg1__aNSEventPtr, ostypes.HELPER.sel('type'));

    cType = ctypes.cast(cType, ostypes.TYPE.NSEventType);


    return objc_arg1__aNSEventPtr; // return null to block
};
myHandler_c = ostypes.TYPE.IMP_for_EventMonitorCallback.ptr(myHandler_js);
myBlock_c = ostypes.HELPER.createBlock(myHandler_c);


var rez_add = ostypes.API('objc_msgSend')(ostypes.HELPER.class('NSEvent'), ostypes.HELPER.sel('addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:'), ostypes.TYPE.NSEventMask(ostypes.CONST.NSKeyDownMask), myBlock_c.address());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `CGEventTap`.

This one is having issues but Ill update it as soon as its ready:

```
GetCurrentProcess(psn);

var mask =  1 << kCGEventLeftMouseDown | // CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown)
            1 << kCGEventLeftMouseUp | 
            1 << kCGEventRightMouseDown |
            1 << kCGEventRightMouseUp |
            1 << kCGEventOtherMouseDown |
            1 << kCGEventOtherMouseUp |
            1 << kCGEventScrollWheel;

mouseEventTap = CGEventTapCreateForPSN(&psn, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, mask, null);

if (!mouseEventTap.isNull()) {
      aRLS = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, mouseEventTap, 0);
      CFRelease(mouseEventTap);

      if (!aRLS.isNull()) {
            aLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();

            CFRunLoopAddSource(aLoop, aRLS, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

            CFRelease(aRLS);
            CFRelease(aLoop);

            rez = CFRunLoopRunInMode(ostypes.CONST.kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 10, false); // figure out how to make this run indefinitely
            // rez is 1 :(

      }

}
```